# Inserting an element in a specific location in a multi-dimensional list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I am trying to insert an element at a particular instance in the multi-dimensional list:

```
eg_list = [[['DF1 IN Element', ['DF_CAT1_APPLE_SELECT', 'Element_TO()', '1']], ['DOG Element', ['DF1_CAT_en', 1.0, 'DF_CAT1_DOG', 'Element_TO()', '1']], ['BANANA Element', ['DF_CAT1_BANANA', 'Element_TO()', '1']]], [['DF2 IN Element', ['DF_CAT2_APPLE_SELECT', 'Element_TO()', '1']], ['DOG Element', ['DF_CAT2_DOG', 'Element_TO()', '1']], ['BANANA Element', ['DF_CAT2_BANANA', 'Element_TO()', '1']]], [['MB1 IN ENABLE', ['MB_CAT1_APPLE_SELECT', 'Element_TO()', '1']], ['DOG Element', ['MB_CAT1_DOG', 'Element_TO()', '1']], ['BANANA Element', ['MB_CAT1_BANANA', 'Element_TO()', '1']]], [['MB2 IN ENABLE', ['MB_CAT2_APPLE_SELECT', 'Element_TO()', '1']], ['DOG Element', ['MB_CAT2_DOG', 'Element_TO()', '1']], ['BANANA Element', ['MB_CAT2_BANANA', 'Element_TO()', '1']]], [['ABC1 IN ENABLE', ['ABC_CAT1_APPLE_SELECT', 'Element_TO()', '1']], ['DOG Element', ['ABC_CAT1_DOG', 'Element_TO()', '1']], ['BANANA Element', ['ABC_CAT1_BANANA', 'Element_TO()', '1']]]]

for i in range(0, len(eg_list)):
    for j in range(0, len(eg_list[i])):
        for k in range(0, len(eg_list[i][j][1])):
            if eg_list[i][j][1][k] == 'Element_TO()':
                eg_list.insert([i][j][1][k], 'MAIN')
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is if it finds, 'Element_TO()' in the list then I am trying to insert 'MAIN' after that element. The output I am looking for is -

```
[[['DF1 IN Element', ['DF_CAT1_APPLE_SELECT', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']], ['DOG Element', ['DF1_CAT_en', 1.0, 'DF_CAT1_DOG', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']], ['BANANA Element', ['DF_CAT1_BANANA', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']]], [['DF2 IN Element', ['DF_CAT2_APPLE_SELECT', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']], ['DOG Element', ['DF_CAT2_DOG', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']], ['BANANA Element', ['DF_CAT2_BANANA', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']]], [['MB1 IN ENABLE', ['MB_CAT1_APPLE_SELECT', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']], ['DOG Element', ['MB_CAT1_DOG', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']], ['BANANA Element', ['MB_CAT1_BANANA', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']]], [['MB2 IN ENABLE', ['MB_CAT2_APPLE_SELECT', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']], ['DOG Element', ['MB_CAT2_DOG', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']], ['BANANA Element', ['MB_CAT2_BANANA', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']]], [['ABC1 IN ENABLE', ['ABC_CAT1_APPLE_SELECT', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']], ['DOG Element', ['ABC_CAT1_DOG', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']], ['BANANA Element', ['ABC_CAT1_BANANA', 'Element_TO()', 'MAIN', '1']]]]
```

How can I get this?

EDIT - Posted another question with the contents of this question for a little more generalized solution. Link to that question - [link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400119/inserting-an-element-in-a-specific-location-only-in-one-of-the-lists-in-a-multi?noredirect=1#comment120884590_68400119)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use recursion for the task:

```py
def add(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        if "Element_TO()" in l:
            l.insert(l.index("Element_TO()") + 1, "MAIN")
        for v in l:
            add(v)


add(eg_list)
print(eg_list)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [
        [
            "DF1 IN Element",
            ["DF_CAT1_APPLE_SELECT", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"],
        ],
        [
            "DOG Element",
            ["DF1_CAT_en", 1.0, "DF_CAT1_DOG", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"],
        ],
        ["BANANA Element", ["DF_CAT1_BANANA", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"]],
    ],
    [
        [
            "DF2 IN Element",
            ["DF_CAT2_APPLE_SELECT", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"],
        ],
        ["DOG Element", ["DF_CAT2_DOG", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"]],
        ["BANANA Element", ["DF_CAT2_BANANA", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"]],
    ],
    [
        [
            "MB1 IN ENABLE",
            ["MB_CAT1_APPLE_SELECT", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"],
        ],
        ["DOG Element", ["MB_CAT1_DOG", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"]],
        ["BANANA Element", ["MB_CAT1_BANANA", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"]],
    ],
    [
        [
            "MB2 IN ENABLE",
            ["MB_CAT2_APPLE_SELECT", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"],
        ],
        ["DOG Element", ["MB_CAT2_DOG", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"]],
        ["BANANA Element", ["MB_CAT2_BANANA", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"]],
    ],
    [
        [
            "ABC1 IN ENABLE",
            ["ABC_CAT1_APPLE_SELECT", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"],
        ],
        ["DOG Element", ["ABC_CAT1_DOG", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"]],
        ["BANANA Element", ["ABC_CAT1_BANANA", "Element_TO()", "MAIN", "1"]],
    ],
]
```

Comment: what if there are multiple instances of 'Element_TO()' in outer and inner lists and I only want to insert elements in inner lists, not outer lists. This method works for this particular case but what if I want to change it only in the inner list. How to do that?

Comment: @ShivamGupta If I understand you correctly you can perform additional check before the insert: check if the list doesn't contain other list and if not, insert the "MAIN"

Comment: I am new to python, could you please tell me how to do that? How to insert only in a particular list? How to check if there is no other list inside the list.

Comment: @ShivamGupta To not clutter the comment section I'd recommend to open a new question here on Stack Overflow (where you put what you've tried so far). I'll try to look at it.

Comment: I have posted another question. Please have a look at it. "Inserting an element in a specific location only in one of the lists in a multi-dimensional list"